tailwindcss background not changing to correct color
There is a feature i implemented in the tiktaktoe wherein if a player wins the game, then the winning box gets green in color and if there is a draw , then all the box becomes red. The feature is working fine. But when i close my Vs CODE or close the terminal and then start it again , the above mentioned feature doesn't work. Then again when i change the color value of modify it a little and save it then again it runs properly

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const TikTakToe = () => {
  const [matrix, setMatrix] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
  const [turn, setTurn] = useState(true);
  const [won, setWon] = useState(null);
  const [winConfig, setWinConfig] = useState([]);

  // Initialize state when component mounts
  useEffect(() => {
    setMatrix(Array(9).fill(null));
    setTurn(true);
    setWon(null);
    setWinConfig([]);
  }, []);

  // Click handler for each grid cell
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    const res = parseInt(e.target.id);
    if (!matrix[res] && !won) {
      let tempM = [...matrix];
      tempM[res] = turn ? 'O' : 'X';
      setMatrix(tempM);
      setTurn(!turn);
    }
  };

  // Effect to check for win or draw
  useEffect(() => {
    const arrangement = [
      [0, 1, 2],
      [3, 4, 5],
      [6, 7, 8],
      [0, 3, 6],
      [1, 4, 7],
      [2, 5, 8],
      [0, 4, 8],
      [2, 4, 6],
    ];

    // Check for draw
    if (!matrix.includes(null) && !won) {
      setWon('D');
    }

    // Check for win
    for (let i = 0; i < arrangement.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = arrangement[i];
      if (matrix[a] && matrix[a] === matrix[b] && matrix[a] === matrix[c]) {
        setWon(matrix[a]);
        setWinConfig([a, b, c]);
        break; // Stop checking further arrangements once a winner is found
      }
    }
  }, [matrix, won]);

  // Reset game handler
  const resetHandler = () => {
    setMatrix(Array(9).fill(null));
    setTurn(true);
    setWon(null);
    setWinConfig([]);
  };

  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-7 h-[500px] '>
      <h1 className='text-center text-3xl font-bold'>TIC TAC TOE</h1>
      <div className='grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3'>
        {matrix.map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={`w-20 h-20 border border-black bg-slate-400 hover:bg-white cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center text-3xl ${
              matrix[index] ? 'pointer-events-none bg-slate-300' : ''
            } ${winConfig.includes(index) ? 'bg-green-400' : ''} ${
              won === 'D' ? 'bg-red-800' : ''
            }`}
            id={index}
            onClick={!item && !won ? clickHandler : undefined}
          >
            {item}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center gap-3'>
        <button className='border border-black h-10 w-20 rounded-md hover:bg-red-400 transition-colors duration-100 ease-in' onClick={resetHandler}>
          Reset
        </button>
        {won ? (
          <>
            {won === 'D' ? (
              <div>It's a Draw!!</div>
            ) : (
              <div>Player {won} won the match!</div>
            )}
          </>
        ) : (
          <div>Player: {turn ? 'O' : 'X'}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TikTakToe;

the above code is what i implemented

In your code, you've specified the background multiple times. The specificity of these selectors is the same, so the styles that appear later in the stylesheet will override the ones that appear earlier. However, in Tailwind, the order of styles isn't explicitly defined and might be related to which utility class is used first. This leads to the unpredictable behavior described in your problem.

Firstly, my suggestion is the same as @Santi's: avoid concatenating class strings and use clsx to improve readability.
Secondly, to solve this problem, there are two approaches:

Increase the specificity of certain selectors to prevent conflicts between them. (which is not very realistic in this case).
Avoid adding selectors with the same specificity for the same property.

This case works best using approach 2:
import clsx from "clsx";

// ...

function getWinColor() {
  if (matrix[index]) return "bg-slate-300";
  if (winConfig.includes(index)) return "bg-green-400";
  if (won === "D") return "bg-red-800";
  return "bg-slate-400";
}

<div
  className={clsx(
    "flex h-20 w-20 cursor-pointer items-center justify-center border border-black text-3xl hover:bg-white",
    matrix[index] && "pointer-events-none",
    getWinColor(),
  )}
/>


This is just one example. The exact priority of getWinColor should be up to you.
Don't forget to move the default color bg-slate-400 to the getWinColor function as well.


I would use clsx and/or tailwindmerge (twmerge). Using template literals is not best practice for conditional styling and can lead to these issues.
It would look like this then:
<div
  key={index}
  className={clsx(
    'w-20 h-20 border border-black bg-slate-400 hover:bg-white cursor-pointer flex items-center justify-center text-3xl',
    {
      'pointer-events-none bg-slate-300': matrix[index],
      'bg-green-400': winConfig.includes(index),
      'bg-red-800': won === 'D'
    }
  )}
  id={index}
  onClick={!item && !won ? clickHandler : undefined}
>
  {item}
</div>

Don't forget to install clsx and import it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

This answer does not explain the cause of the issue but only provides a solution. Please update your answer with why the code of the OP is not working

I tried to implement clsk but this also doesnt seem to have any effect. When the a player wins the match it is not changing the color of the blocks.
